# How many ordered bases can be found for $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ over filed $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Take $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ as a linear space over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Now you can imagine multy bases for this space. (please leave a comment or have an edit if question is not clear enough.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first basis vector can be any nonzero vector ($p^n-1$ possibilities). 
The second basis vector can be chosen from anywhere except the 1d subspace of the first vector ($p^n-p$ possibilities). 
The third vector can be anywhere except the 2d subspace spanned by the first two vectors ($p^n-p^2$ possibilities).

All in all, the number of ordered bases is
$$(p^n-1)(p^n-p)(p^n-p^2)\dots(p^n-p^{n-1})\,.$$

Comment: I receive this answer too. But is it divisible over $n!$?

Comment: @HoseynHeydari It should be because all vectors in a base are different, so you can group all permutations of a given base into a single block of size $n!$.